# React-redux component not re-rendering on store props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My react component is not re-rendering despite its props being updated  and I don't understand why.

Here's my component

```
import { fetchLocations } from 'state/locations/actions';

class Event extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchLocations();
  }

  render() {
    const { locations } = this.props;

    return <span>{locations.map((l) => {return <span>{l}</span>;})}</span>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  locations: state.locations
})

export default connect(                                                                                                                                               
  mapStateToProps,                                                                                                                                                    
  { fetchLocations },                                                                                                                                                 
)(Event);
```

Here is my locations action file

```
export const fetchLocations = () = (dispatch) => {
  axios.get('/api/locations')
  .then(response => {
    const locations = response.data;

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_LOCATIONS_SUCCESS, payload: locations });
  });
}
```

And my entities reducer

```
function entities(state = { locations: {} }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LOCATIONS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        locations: action.payload
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

After this, my `Event` component should re-render. It doesn't. Using the react dev tools chrome extension I see that the locations are indeed there as `props`, but they do not show on the UI.

If I unmount the component by going to a different page and re-mount it, the locations show up properly.

It looks like everything works fine except the re-render is not triggering. `componentDidUpdate` is never fired.

If I manually do a `setTimeout` to `forceUpdate` an arbitrary second later, they show up.

Why isn't my component re-rendering?

Comment: Have u tried `console.log()` inside `componentDidUpdate` to see if it's firing? Also, this doesn't look like the full code, can you post the full code instead?

Comment: @RohitKashyap yep, it's not firing. The other code is not really related to the problem imo, what other code are you referring to?

Comment: You have assigned locations as an object in your initial state inside the reducer, you are trying to map over an object, either set locations as an empty array or ''

Comment: Sorry, I omitted something. I forgot to set locations inside my render function. `locations` is properly set like that in my code too.

Answer (score -1):

Please, try to add key prop to span element of the render method. `locations.map((l,key)=> <span key={key} >{l} </span>`